# obtener la extensión de un fichero de un array en una petición feature.get

Tags: javascript

Estoy obteniendo los datos de un JSON que recibo de una consulta PHP y los estoy mostrando en un div. Entre ellos recibo los de un columna de la BD que contiene imágenes (jpg) y vídeos (mp4). Quería poder diferenciarlos, si quiero mostrar imágenes me gustaría hacerlo de una manera y si es un vídeo de otra.
Así muestro los datos en el div:

```
...
var records = document.getElementById('infoDIV');
    records.innerHTML = '';
    var html = '';
    for (i=0; i<features.length; i++){
    if(features[i].get('imagen') !=null){
        records.innerHTML += '<div class="image"><a href="' + features[i].get('imagen') + '" target="_blank" onClick="window.open(this.href, this.target); return false;"><img id= "myBtn" class = "iob" src=' + features[i].get('imagen') + '></a></div>';
    }else{
        records.innerHTML += '<img class = "iobs" src=images/imagedummie.jpg>';
    }
}   
...
```

Los datos que me devuelve, por ejemplo:

```
id_code: "140133"
autor: "Carmen GS"
id_image_observation: "97"
id_observation: "1241"
id_observation_font: "1"
imagen: "IMG/Cangulata_20201117_CGS.jpg"
lat: "43.554666"
long: "-3.424316"
obs_date: "2020-11-17"
```

Si en la respuesta viene un vídeo:

```
id_code: "137209"
autor: "Manuel Pérez"
id_image_observation: "105"
id_observation: "1249"
id_observation_font: "1"
imagen: "IMG/Dcoriacea_20201125_AMunhoz.mp4"
lat: "43.578522"
long: "-6.843254"
obs_date: "2020-11-24"
```

Querría poder decir si ese features[i].get('imagen') tiene la extensión jpg, me muestras la imagen, si al contrario tiene la extensión mp4 me muestras el vídeo. Supongo que hacer algo así, sería mejor que crear una nueva columna en la BD para los vídeos y separarlos, no?

Comment: ¿Puedes hacer un `console.log()` de `features` y mostrarnos la estructura de sus datos? Para hacer esto **edita** tu pregunta por favor.

Comment: ¿Y si fuese un video? ¿Existe una propiedad que se llama `video`? ¿Deja de existir la propiedad `imagen`? No puedo adivinar con qué datos estas trabajando, te recomiendo que te leas [¿Cómo elaboro una buena pregunta?](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Si quieres revisar si la llave `imagen` existe, solo tienes que utilizar un `in`:

```js
const datos = [{
    id: 1,
    imagen: "imagen.jpg"
  },
  {
    id: 3,
    video: "video.mp4"
  }
];

for (dato of datos) {
  if ("imagen" in dato) {
    console.log(`El dato con id ${dato.id} es una imagen.`);
  } else {
    console.log(`El dato con id ${dato.id} es un video.`);
  }
}
```

Espero haberte entendido y que te haya sido de ayuda el ejemplo. Te recomiendo tener cuidado porque `in` también revisa las propiedades prototipo del objeto.

Comment: Perdón estuve liada con algún examen, vale, gracias, lo probaré por si esto me puede valer.